# Backbone fetch and 204 server responses

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

When I run

`.fetch({success: testSuccess})`

using:

```
testSuccess: function(collection, response) {
  console.log(response) // => null 
}
```

I get null for response.

This happens when the response is 204.  Is there a work around?  Why wouldn't the response object be present?  It is my understanding that this is the proper callback for the backbone fetch, as I've used it previously with error handling with 400 code server responses.

Comment: Shouldn't it be correct? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#2xx_Success 204 Code stands for success with no response content

Comment: Response represents all of the response at least for errors, like `response.status` which should, in my opinion, be `== 204`.